# Truncate text encoding safe

Tags: postgresql

What would be the most efficient way, within Postgres, to truncate a `text` field to a maximum number of bytes, in such a way that the encoding is preserved?
I.e. how to keep at most N bytes while keeping a valid UTF8 string representation.

E.g. assuming UTF8, if a field contains `abc€`, that's 4 characters for 5 bytes, if I want to truncate this field to at most 4 bytes, but keep a valid UTF8 string, I'd need to actually keep only the first 3 bytes.

I feel like I need the following, but instead of `'escape'`, I'd like to ignore the invalid bytes to only keep `abc`:

```
select encode(substring('abc€'::bytea, 0, 5), 'escape');
 encode  
---------
 abc\342
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: normally one does not care how many bytes a string is eating up just how many characters that is allotted  in the column.   the easiest way to cut string to a specific length  mystring::char(5)  this would return mystr.  The question becomes why are you trying to do this in the database

Comment: I have a case where a field is given to a function that refuses values longer than 256 bytes (through an extension), hence my need to truncate to a given number of bytes, but I also want to keep a valid string representation.

Comment: what Postgresql extension is doing that?  Is this inhouse or common available extension

Comment: In UTF8 all bytes of multibyte sequences have the high-order bit set, so you can peek at the byte at the truncation offset and go backward until finding a byte with the high-order bit cleared, and then truncate just after it.

Comment: @DanielVérité that makes sense. Wouldn't it mean if the truncation leaves a multi-byte character at the end of the string, it would necessarily be removed, even if "complete" ?

Comment: @Sylvain: possibly, but that can probably be arranged depending on whether the first byte you peek at is the byte that is off-limit or the rightmost byte that is allowed to stay after the truncation. I think only in the latter case you may suppress a multibyte character that could have been kept.

Comment: @DanielVérité  I do not see how one could do what you propose in Postgresql,  the bytea string functions are limited.

Comment: @zsheep: there is `get_byte(bytea,int)` to peek at a byte and the binary AND to test the high-order bit. As for efficiency, if it can be implemented as an SQL function it could be okay, otherwise in plpgsql I wouldn't bet anything on it :)

Comment: @DanielVérité  am I missing something here,  get_byte  returns an integer position of the bytea, then one would have to use get_bit() to extract the  binary.  I see a loop inside a loop to process this from right to left using just bytes looking for the high order bytea...  logic seems more complicated

Comment: @zsheep: please see the implementation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_prefix (
   string text,
   max_bytes bigint
) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql STRICT AS
$$SELECT p
FROM (SELECT p.p, octet_length(p.p) AS len
      FROM generate_series(0, length($1)) AS len
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL substr($1, 1, len.len) AS p) AS q
WHERE len <= $2
ORDER BY len DESC
LIMIT 1$$;
```

It works like this:

```
SELECT get_prefix('abc€', 4);
 get_prefix 
------------
 abc
(1 row)
```

Comment: just finish writing one

Comment: thanks, I get the idea. I guess to optimize the brute force approach, for UTF8 encoding, we could start at offset "length($1)/4".

Comment: Not quite, but I get what you mean. You would replace the `0` in `generate_series` with `$2 / 4`.

Answer (score 1):

here is another one written PL/pgSQL

```
Create or Replace function max_bytea_length(pchars text, bytea_length int)
RETURNS bytea
LANGUAGE plpgsql

COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

declare 
_i int;
_length_of_chars int;
_newchars text;
_testchars text;
begin

if octet_length(pchars::bytea) <= bytea_length then
   return pchars::bytea;
end if;
_i = least( octet_length(pchars)-4, bytea_length-4);
_length_of_chars =  char_length(pchars);
loop 
   _newchars= left(pchars, _i);
    _testchars = left(pchars, _i+1); 
  if octet_length(_testchars::bytea) > bytea_length or _i = _length_of_chars  then
     return _newchars::bytea;
  end if ;
  _i = _i+1;
end loop ;

end;
$BODY$
```

-

```
select max_bytea_length( 'abc€', 4 )::char(10)
'abc'
```

-

```
select max_bytea_length('i ♥ u function changed it to be faster', 56)::char(60)
```

Comment: thanks, there's a small typo: `left(pchars, _i+);`  should be `left(pchars, _i+1);`

Similarly to above I think the first offset could be `bytea_length/4` instead of 0.

Testing locally both answers, yours performs much faster (2ms vs 50ms for 5 bytes input)

Comment: yup that is a typo,  The reason this preforms better is Albe is generating an entire record set for the string,  for each byte there is a new row,  the longer the string the more rows, then there is an order by and where clause.  I'll fix my typo

Comment: bytea_length/4   I do not understand you.      there is a logic test   if  octet_length(pchars::bytea) <= bytea_length     this escapes out of the function if the passed in string less than the bytea_length.    the loop is doing string manipulation by going left to right 1 character at a time then jumping one character ahead to see if octet_length greater than bytea_length.   and to make sure we do not end up in an endless loop  _i is compared to the string length..

Comment: assuming UTF8, if you're looking for at most N bytes, you know you can take at least N/4 characters, since a character can't use more than 4 bytes.

Comment: I see where you coming from now,  this function is not manipulating the byteas of the string.     that would be allot harder in SQL and i do not think there would be any performance improvement.    The only why to improve the speed would be take my function is rewrite in C.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-binarystring.html     https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: What i mean is to declare `_i int = greatest(1, bytea_length / 4);` so for long string and large `bytea_length` values, there is less useless iterations.

Comment: i see it will help a bit but not much      select char_length('i ♥ u function but what is  wanted do does not help that much   '),  greatest(1,    56/ 4)   this only skips the first 14 characters,     another option would be this         select char_length('i ♥ u function but what you want to do does not help that much'),  
least( octet_length('i ♥ u function but what you want to do does not help that much')-4, 56-4)   this jumps over almost the entire string

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for UTF-8 that is based on checking for non-leading bytes in the UTF-8 representation.

The implementation is pure SQL (non-procedural) to benefit from inlining, and uses CASE WHEN... constructs to implement the if-then-else logic.

The idea implemented by the query is:
firstly, check if the octet length is already less than the limit, and if yes,  return right away the original string.
Otherwise, check if the byte at the right of the candidate truncation point is part of a sequence, if no, truncate, otherwise move the truncation point to the left until it does not break a sequence.

A UTF-8 byte in a valid string is in one of these 3 categories:

- single byte character (bitstring `0xxxxxxx` testable with `byte & 128 = 0`)
- first byte of a multibyte sequence (bitstring `11xxxxxx` testable with `byte & 192 = 192`)
- 2nd or 3rd or 4th byte of a multibyte sequence (bitstring `10xxxxxx` testable with `byte & 192 = 128`)

If the byte at the right of the putative cutoff point is of the first or second category, we can truncate safely just before that byte, excluding it. Otherwise it's of the third category, and we need to test up to 3 more bytes backwards  until finding a byte that is not of the third category, or the string is too short and the result is the empty string.

The code:

```sql
create function utf8_truncate(str text, len int) returns text
as $$
select case when octet_length(str) <= len then str
else (
   with bstr(s) as (select convert_to(str, 'UTF-8'))
   select
   case
   when len>=1 and (get_byte(s, len) & 192) <> 128
   then convert_from(substring(s, 1, len), 'UTF-8')
   else
     case
     when len>=2 and (get_byte(s, len-1) & 192) <> 128
     then convert_from(substring(s, 1, len-1), 'UTF-8')
     else
       case
       when len>=3 and (get_byte(s, len-2) & 192) <> 128
       then convert_from(substring(s, 1, len-2), 'UTF-8')
       else
         case
         when len>=4 and (get_byte(s, len-3) & 192) <> 128
         then convert_from(substring(s, 1, len-3), 'UTF-8')
         else ''
         end
       end
     end
   end
 from bstr)
   end;
$$ language sql strict immutable parallel safe;
```

Some notes:

- in `get_byte(bytea, int)`, the offsets start at 0, whereas in `substring(bytea, int, int)` the offsets start at 1.
- the example in the question casts `text` to `bytea` to get the byte representation, but that's not correct: if the text contains backslashes, they will be interpreted as escape sequences of the [bytea escape format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html). `convert_to()` should be used instead.

Comment: is it ok if i take your code and stick on wiki.postgresql.org code snippets with mine,

Comment: @zsheep: you don't need my permission to republish but you need to abide by stackexchange license terms. See the footer at the bottom of this page if you're not familiar with them yet.

Comment: i read over the Terms for stack overflow,  as best as i can read its free to use as long as the authors are noted..    https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuncate_text_by_byte